# How to reconstruct file from base64 to pdf in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Nodejs, I'm getting response from an api

```
{
  "file": "PHN0eWxlPnRlRrU3VRbUNDJyAvPjwvcD4K",
  "mime_type": "text/html",
  "document_type": "shippingLabel"
}
```

To reconstruct the file, the data from the  node needs to be base64 decoded, and interpreted according to the mime_type.

Help me to get the file in `.pdf`  and save to directory.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: FYI, that is an encoding of the UTF8 string `<style>teFµ7UÔ42róãÂ÷à`, not sure if that's what it's supposed to be...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes it's showing output ` <style>teFµ7UÔ42róãÂ÷à ` .  when i decoded it giving ERROR: invalid input . May be document data is not valid. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding):

```
const fs = require('fs');

// get your response somehow...
const response = {
  file: 'PHN0eWxlPnRlRrU3VRbUNDJyAvPjwvcD4K',
  mime_type: 'text/html',
  document_type: 'shippingLabel'
};
// LUT for MIME type to extension
const ext = {
  'text/html': 'html',
  // ...
}

// save to shippingLabel.html
fs.writeFileSync(`${response.document_type}.${ext[response.mime_type]}`, response.file, 'base64');
```